# Woocommerce: woocommerce query for stock quantity simple and varibale products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am going to write a query for woocommerce products to show products that have stock = 1. also if a product is variable and any variables has stock =1 should include in this query. 
for example:

**Product one:**

- simple
- stock quantity: 1

**Product two:**

- simple
- stock quantity: 5

**Product three:**

- variation
- variable one:
- stock quantity: 1
- variable two:
- stock quantity: 4
- variable three:
- stock quantity: 7

**Product four:**

- variation
- variable one:
- stock quantity: 3
- variable two:
- stock quantity: 2
- variable three:
- stock quantity: 5

so the query should return product one and product 3.

I used the below query:

```
$query = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => '_stock_status',
            'value'   => 'instock',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_stock',
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'value'   => '1',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    );
```

But, It won't work return product three. 
would you please help me?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to include post type `product_variation` for variation product  & `product` so you can filter the variable product too.

so you can do the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'modify_query', 10, 2 );

function modify_query( $q, $instance ) {

    $post_type = array( 'product', 'product_variation' );

    $q->set( 'post_type', (array) $post_type );
    $meta_query[] = [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key'     => '_stock_status',
            'value'   => 'instock',
            'compare' => '=',
        ],
        [
            'key'     => '_stock',
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'value'   => '1',
            'compare' => '=',
        ],

    ];

    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I'm using this query in woocommerce default query. so i have to use it in 'woocommerce_product_query' action. 
So, i test it and the result was showing all of the variation in woocommerce archive pages(means duplicate products with the same title and thumbnail but different url). Do you have any idea?

Comment: Also, In your example, the duplicate result is exist there. i need to show the main product as the result if the variation stock is 1. thanks for your help

Comment: @Reza i just modified my answer check it now please